# Terminal autocomplete functionality can only match from the beginning?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

For example, if I type in "`apt-`"and press tab,I can find "`apt-get`" below.But if I type in "`get`", "`apt-get`" cannot appear. How can I do to match not only from the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to search sub strings of all possible commands at a time.

You do though have the option of searching for sub strings of previously typed commands by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then typing your sub string. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> again to cycle through the previously typed commands containing this sub string

Answer (score 1):

`zsh` might be able to get you halfway there:

[image]
[image]

For me, `zsh` seems to prefer prefix completions (`file<tab>` will get me `file filefrag file-roller`, `-file<tab>` will get me `apt-file desktop-file-install ecryptfs-rewrite-file grub-file ...`). I don't understand the completion system well enough to make zsh do substring matching even if prefix matching works. My completion options:

```
# The following lines were added by compinstall

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored
zstyle ':completion:*' list-suffixes true
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'r:|[._-]=** r:|=**' 'l:|=* r:|=*' 'm:{[:lower:][:upper:]}={[:upper:][:lower:]}'
zstyle ':completion:*' squeeze-slashes true

autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# End of lines added by compinstall
```

Comment: fish also seems to support this.