# What does _expand do?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, functions

I was working with the shell, and by mistake I autocompleted with <kbd>tab</kbd> after writing `_e`, which resulted in `_expand`.

What does this command do? I couldn't find an explanation online, the only references I could find here on Ask Ubuntu were:

- [Cannot change zsh prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90254/cannot-change-zsh-prompt)
- [Terminal autocomplete functionality can only match from the beginning?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/653557/terminal-autocomplete-functionality-can-only-match-from-the-beginning/653617#653617)

But they don't answer my question. Instead, they open up more questions of the same kind about commands like `_complete`, `_complete_as_root`, etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can find out what `_expand` does, when typing

```
$ type _expand
_expand is a function
_expand ()
{
    if [[ "$cur" == \~*/* ]]; then
        eval cur=$cur;
    else
        if [[ "$cur" == \~* ]]; then
            cur=${cur#\~};
            COMPREPLY=($( compgen -P '~' -u "$cur" ));
            [ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ] && eval COMPREPLY[0]=${COMPREPLY[0]};
            return ${#COMPREPLY[@]};
        fi;
    fi
}
```

This is a function in the bash completion mechanism. It expands tildes (`~`) in pathnames. In `/etc/bash_completion` is a comment about the function:

```
# Expand ~username type directory specifications.  We want to expand
# ~foo/... to /home/foo/... to avoid problems when $cur starting with
# a tilde is fed to commands and ending up quoted instead of expanded.
```

---

Try it in a terminal, type:

```
~<tab><tab>
```

It will expand to the usernames, for example

```
~usera     ~userb     ~userc
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the command `type`. It wasn't clear to me why I could not call these functions as `_function_name [argument]`, but now I understand that they serve their purpose as autocomplete extensions, and the fact that they appear in my autocomplete is simply because they are declared (but they are not meant to be called directly).

Comment: Exactly the `_expand` function, as all other complete functions, just manipulates the `COMPREPLY` array, based on values of `$cur` which contains the completion pattern.